# How to fix java runtime error for wriritng code to check if the UPC is valid?

Tags: java, branch, nested-loops

I want to write a java program that can check if the UPC code is valid or not by using only 'nested while loops' and 'branching: if-else'. here is the formula to check if the UPC is valid:

1. From left to right, add the digits in the odd-numbered positions
   (starting the count from 1) and multiply the result by 3.
2. From left to right, add the digits in the even-numbered positions to the total
   computed in step 1
3. Take the result from step 2 and compute the
   remainder when divided by 10 (result modulo 10). If the remainder
   is not zero, subtract this remainder from 10 to get the check digit.
   If the remainder is zero, then the check digit should be 0.

Note: the code is keep asking until it receive blank input.

**I had input the numbers but it show nothing so what should i do, thank!**

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
    String upc = in.nextLine(); 
    while (upc.length() <12 && upc.length()>0) {
        int even= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(2))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(4))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(6))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(8))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(10));
        int odd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(1))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(3))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(5))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(7))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(9))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11));
        int sum= even*3+odd;
        int cd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11));
        if (sum%10 !=0) {
            int sub= 10-(sum%10);
            if (sub==cd) {
                System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +sub);
                System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ cd);
                System.out.println("valid");
                System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                upc= in.nextLine();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +sub);
                System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ cd);
                System.out.println("not valid");
                System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                upc= in.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

    if (upc.length()==0) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
```

Comment: Did you press `Enter` after you typed in the numbers?

Comment: What run-time error are you getting? Post it with a complete stack trace?

Comment: after i press enter it show nothing only black screen.

Comment: Run it under debugger and you will be able to see step-by-step execution.

Comment: I had use eclipse to run for debug, it still show nothing too, which is weird and here what is look like when i  run it in command:  http://i57.tinypic.com/zxjm0i.png

Comment: What was the value of `sum`?

Comment: i see thank, that because i made a small mistake in the odd integer also the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very easy fix to get it to run. But you still have a lot of code to add so it loops, and also accounts for the user entering a blank string or a string that is not 12 characters.

The easy fix, so it runs, is as follows.

1. Your even and odd variables are switched. Saying charAt(0) is a odd number. So switch those 2 variable names around.
2. On the even variable you do not need to add Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11)). charAt(11) is the check digit, and does not need to be accounted for when adding.
3. In order to start the while loop you need to make it "upc.length() <= 12", currently your while loop is only working if the string is less than 12, which is incorrect.

So as for now, this code below will allow your code to run, but remember you have a little ways to go so it functions as you want it to, if you need help just ask.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UPC_Check {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
        String upc = in.nextLine(); 
        while (upc.length() <= 12 && upc.length()>0) {
            int odd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(2))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(4))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(6))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(8))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(10));
            int even= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(1))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(3))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(5))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(7))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(9));
            int sum= odd*3+even;
            int cd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11));

            if (sum%10 !=0) {
                int sub= 10-(sum%10);
                if (sub==cd) {
                    System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +sub);
                    System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ cd);
                    System.out.println("valid");
                    System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                    upc= in.nextLine();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +sub);
                    System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ cd);
                    System.out.println("not valid");
                    System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                    upc= in.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }

        if (upc.length()==0) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining! now i'm clear yes i had change some variable in loop as if the user is input less or more than 12 digits, it will show a message for them enter again either!